# Given n, take tsum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing a single-digit number is produced

Tags: python

```
def digital_root(n):
    x = str(n)
    while len(x)!=0 and len(x)!=1:
        r = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            r= r + int(x[i])
        x = str(r)
    return r
```

A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number. Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

My code:

Is this code efficient? I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    test.assert_equals( digital_root(0), 0 )
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 8, in digital_root
    return r
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like r is out of scope when you reach the return statement. It only applies locally within the while statement, which ends before the return statement.

It's good that you only have one return statement and that it is at the broadest scope for the function, and at the end. So, try declaring r as n outside of the while loop, in the same scope as the return statement. That scope includes everything inside the while loop as well.

```
def digital_root(n):
    x = str(n)
    r = n
    while len(x) > 1:
        r = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            r = r + int(x[i])
        x = str(r)
    return r
```

Comment: Yep, I would try the recursive solution offered by another answerer, @Joran Beasley. But, figuring out your initial approach is a worthwhile exercise. You'll notice that it only times out for bigger numbers, numbers in which your first sum (r) is still more than one digit. You'll also notice that when you keyboard interrupt to get out of the loop (ctrl+c), the error message says you interrupted at ```r = r + int(x[i])```. What do you think is happening there?

Comment: Ah, I figured out our problem. We should have left r as resetting to zero within the while loop when we moved its initialization outside of the loop. Editing the solution now.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with recursion

```
def root_sum(n):
    x = sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
    if x > 9:
       return root_sum(x)
    return x
```

that is the easiest solution imho

Comment: I wasnt aware of the map function. I am  new to python and programming so I was trying to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the string `x` is 1 (you can also just ask if the length is greater than 1 for the while loop), the code skips straight to returning `r`. However, it may not know what `r` refers to because it only gets assigned inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

had the same task in codewars. This is the optimal solution:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(map(int, str(n))))
```